# Is It possible if i have put message to ActiveMq jms and consume it from RabbitMq jms?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am new to jms,
I have did poc of spring jms with ActiveMq. In which I am producing messages in queue and consume it using consumer and one  poc in which I am using spring jms with rabbitmq  with producer and consumer and have added plugin of jms in rabbit mq to use spring jms with rabbitmq.

Is it Possible if I put Produce message in active MQ and Consume that messages using spring jms rabbitmq consumer?

Is It possible if yes then How?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ are two different brokers - why do you need (and why do you think it's possible) to send messages to one broker and receive them from another?

You would need another application to move the messages; it's not clear why you would want to do that.

Comment: thanks for your reply
I was doing R&D.I was using pivotal rabbit mq service in which JMS plugin was already install.One team is going to produce msg in ACTIVE MQ and I want that message to be consumed in RABBIT MQ.

Comment: You would need another application to receive them from ActiveMQ and publish them to RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, **you would need an adapter layer to move the JMS messages from one MQ to another** (i.e., active MQ to Rabbitmq etc.).

You can look [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jms_adapters.html) for some notes (IBM specific) on JMS adapters, but the underlying concept is the same i.e., consuming from one MQ and producing the messages to another MQ.